# How to Resolve React nested component circular dependency?

Tags: reactjs, circular-dependency, rollup

When using componentSelector in Item3, I'm getting a Circular Dependency warning.
How can I address this?

*componentSelector.tsx*

```
export const componentSelector = {
  item1: Item1,
  item2: Item2,
  item3: **Item3**,
  item4: Item4,
}
```

*Item3.tsx*

```
import { componentSelector } from '';

const Item3 = () => {

 const Component = componentSelector[name];

  return (
        ...

          {Component ? <Component {...props} /> : <></>}
        ...
  );
};

export default Item3;
```